# Cannot access associated model attributes within a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, model, has-many-through

I am trying to build a form for a has_many :through relationship. The Problem is, that I can access the attributes from the join table (:through) in the form, but not the other table.

My models look like this:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :quantities
   has_many :ingredients, through: :quantities
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities
end

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, through: :quantities 
end
```

My Form:

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>


  <div class="quantities">
    <%= f.fields_for :quantities do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'quantity_fields', :f => builder%>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :quantities %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the quantity_fields partial:

```
<p>
<%= f.label :value, "Value" %>
<%= f.text_field :value %>
<%= f.label :unit, "Unit" %>
<%= f.text_field :unit %>
<%= f.text_field :ingredient %>
<%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |builder|%>
  <%= builder.label :name, "Ingredient"%>
  <%= builder.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
</p>
```

The fields for the quantities attributes are correct, but the text field for the ingredient name (within the quantity_fields partial) stays empty.
On the Rails console on the other hand I can easily use the ingredient method on a quantity object and get a result.

I try to find a solution to this since a while now, and it becomes really frustrating to me. I am sure this is a standard task and I am just missing a small part. Can anyone help me?

**Edit:**

Also when I change my recipe form to directly render the ingredients, it doesn't work. The text fields remain empty.

```
<%= form_for(@recipe) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="ingredients">
    <%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>
      <p>
      <%= builder.label :name, "Name" %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>
      <%= builder.label :description, "Description" %>
      <%= builder.text_field :description %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Edit 2:**
The recipes controller:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /recipes
  # GET /recipes.json
  def index
    @recipes = Recipe.all
  end

  # GET /recipes/1
  # GET /recipes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /recipes/new
  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
  end

  # GET /recipes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /recipes
  # POST /recipes.json
  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.save
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /recipes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Recipe was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @recipe }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /recipes/1
  # DELETE /recipes/1.json
  def destroy
    @recipe.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to recipes_url, notice: 'Recipe was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_recipe
      @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, quantities_attributes: [:value, :unit, :recipe, :ingredient, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Comment: Please also post your controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When utilizing a `has_many :through` association in that way, you can set up your models like this:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :quantities
   has_many :ingredients, inverse_of: :recipes

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities
end

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, inverse_of: :ingredients 
end
```

[This article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through) covers nested attributes with has_many :through associations in a similar context. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not fix my problem. As I understand this just builds an empty ingredient so there would be something to show. But I already have associated ingredients and just cannot access them from the view.

Comment: You're right, I definitely misunderstood the question on my first read. I took a second look and rewrote the answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks again. I could finally solve it now. The line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients` in the Quantity model was the key. I did not expect that because I don't want to edit Ingredients through quantities, but ok. Also learned something new about inverse_of. Thanks! :)